# How do I see what permissions my Facebook app is asking users for?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

This seems like a silly question, but I can't figure out how to find exactly what permissions my facebook app asks users for. Ideally, there should be a list somewhere that I can add to/delete from/edit.

When I go to `Apps > my_app > Permissions`, I get a "Configure your permissions" box, but it does not list what permission my app currently asks for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the permissions in the App Settings is for the App Centre only.

The permissions will *actually* be asked in the app only if you add them in your login code.

For eg, if you are using-

1. **PHP SDK**

   ```
   $params = array(
     'scope' => 'perm1','perm2'..
   );

   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
   ```
2. **Javascript SDK**

   ```
   FB.login(function(response) {
     // handle the response
   }, {scope: 'perm1, perm2'});
   ```